# Starting activity with clicking on google map marker infoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have to start some activity with clicking on infoWindow (I can do this with `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()`), but this activity can be different, and I need something else. I should have a possibility to set an ID to every map marker. Can I pass custom ID to every Marker on map? Or how I can create button in `infoWindow` with this id (if I can do this, I can pass this id).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using a HashMap or something similar.  As you iterate over your list of objects and create markers for them, also add the Marker to a list, using the ID of the object as the key, and the marker as the value:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Marker> markerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();
```

...

```
for(MarkerObject obj : this.markerObjects)
{
     //If the marker isn't already being displayed
     if(!markerMap.containsKey(obj.getId()))
     {
         //Add the Marker to the Map and keep track of it 
         this.markerMap.put(obj.getId(), this.mMap.addMarker(getMarkerForObject(obj)));
     }
}
```

Then you can use a OnInfoWindowClickListener to find the object id of the tapped marker in your Map and do something with the corresponding data, like open a new activity with details.

Comment: Thanks! I have already fix this problem with hasp map, HashMap<String, int>, where String is marker.getId() and int is a my id of this marker! Thanks you!

Comment: I'm trying, but I see error =( "Vote Up requires 15 reputation", I have no reputation(